# How to filter by type in Ceylon in an elegant way?

Tags: ceylon

I was hoping the following would work:

```
void takeOnlyStrings(String* s) {
   print(s);
}

{String|Integer*} ab = {"Hi", 1};

takeOnlyStrings(for (item in ab) if (item is String) item);
```

Or even this:

```
Boolean isString(Object o) => (o is String);
takeOnlyStrings(ab.filter(isString));
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for narrowing the type of a value is prefix `is Type val`, for example:

```
void takeOnlyStrings(String* s) {
    print(s);
}

{String|Integer*} ab = {"Hi", 1};

takeOnlyStrings(for (item in ab) if (is String item) item);
```

The syntax `item is String` is just an operator expression that produces a `Boolean` value. It doesn't narrow the type of its argument.

Comment: I could swear I tried that!! The IDE keeps giving errors while you write this kind of thing, which does not help very much... but anyway, why have a (item is String) construct which does not actually narrow the type of the object?? Isn't that just confusing? Or more efficient??

Comment: "The IDE keeps giving errors while you write this kind of thing" WDYM?

Comment: This may be Eclipse's fault... as you write code, instead of giving some good completion suggestions, it just makes almost all lines get red. I'd rather use IntelliJ and can't wait for the Ceylon IntelliJ plugin to get ready!

Comment: regarding why we have two variants of "is": one is a plain boolean expression (item is String) while the other one is a special condition that does narrowing and can only be used inside if, while, assert. The narrowing means you can even create a new value: if (is String stringItem=item) stringItem

Answer (score 5):

Here's a second possibility: in Ceylon 1.2, the new method `Iterable.narrow()` can be used:

```
void takeOnlyStrings(String* s) {
    print(s);
}

{String|Integer*} ab = {"Hi", 1};

takeOnlyStrings(*ab.narrow<String>());
```

Hope that helps!